# Where does this pattern of naming products come from?

Tags: etymology

I noticed that a lot of product names have random, cool-sounding letters in their name. They seem less random though when you realize that a lot of products use the same or similar random letters.

Examples of what I mean:

- Lexus GX (Car)
- Pokémon-*GX* (Trading cards)
- Gatorade GX (Sports drink)
- Buick GX (Another car)
- Windows XP
- Disney XD (TV channel)
- Pokémon XD (Video game)
- Sony XPeria (Phone) (this one's different but it might fall in the same pattern)

It seems a lot of random products follow the same pattern, a letter X accompanied by another letter that just sounds cool with it. Is there a known origin for this naming pattern?

Comment: from the marketing department?

Comment: @Jasen no, my question is where does this arbitrary naming pattern come from. Especially because the letters dont seem to be completely random, it's always specific patterns.

Comment: In many cases they are copying a pattern from an earlier product, not always from the same manufacturer.  "GT", appended to a car name, originally meant "Gran Turismo", but it was copied for cars (and many non-cars) that were clearly not designed for "grand touring", presumably because it seemed "macho".

Comment: our brains make endorphins when we find patterns, even if there is no pattern.

Answer (score 7):

This is more a question of psychology than etymology.

> The resonance of X as a signifier of mysterious precision explains why
>   it’s so common in commerce and branding. The Jaguar X-Type. The 2008
>   Mitsubishi Evolution X. The X2000, Sweden’s high-speed train. The
>   X-Acto knife. Mac OS X. The X game for Nintendo’s Game Boy.
>   Microsoft’s Xbox console. Vitamin Water XXX (with three antioxidants).
>   The X is a California roller coaster (the seats swivel around).
>   Product X is a protein powder for bodybuilders. The X-Vest adds weight
>   for exercise.

Article in Psychology Today, with copious references and links:

[What's So Fascinating About the Letter "X"?](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/evolution-the-self/201603/whats-so-fascinating-about-the-letter-x)

Comment: I'm not sure that "X-Acto" really belongs in the list with those other examples, since it's just a brand-y spelling of "exact-o". (Note that it's even pronounced with the /gz/ of "exact" rather than the /ks/ of "X".) Likewise, the "X" in "Mac OS X" is the Roman numeral, and is officially supposed to be pronounced "ten" rather than "X".

Comment: As well as Mac OS X as @ruakh mentions, the Mitsubishi Evo X was actually the tenth incarnation, and [all have had Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_Lancer_Evolution).

Answer (score 6):

X is often used to abreviate a word that starts the with the "ex" sound like "extended","expanded","extreme" etc. or to represent the number 10 (roman numeral) , or words starting in cross (shape of the letter X)

- Lexus GX   (Grand Crossover)
- IBM PC/XT  (extended technnology)
- MX record  (mail exchanger)

Comment: The XP in Windows XP represented "experience"

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I'm guessing that was a backwards formation -- they chose "experience" because it had sexy X in it.  I once worked on a project called "MAGIC" - machine automated generation of intermediate code.  The wordy name was invented by a wag in a business meeting after someone else attacked the project proposal as being "magic".